# How do I refresh a web controler inside a gridview ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, ascx

How can I refresh a web controller inside a gridview? I have a web controller inside a gridview as you can see here:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="100%" style="background: #F5F5F5">
                <div id="div<%# Eval("contrato_id") %>" style="overflow: auto; display: none; position: relative; left: 15px; overflow: auto">
                    <div class="ExpandTableHeader">
                    </div>
                    <div class="body">
                        <div id="tabs-ComponentesSection" class="menusection">
                            <TWebControl5:WebControl5 ID="Header8" runat="server" />
                        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

I want to refresh the following controller.

```
<TWebControl5:WebControl5 ID="Header8" runat="server" />
```

On the following button click.

```
<asp:Button class="btn btn-primary" ID="btnChooseContract" runat="server" Text="Elegir contrato" OnClick="AddContractToQuote" />
```

Here is the code behind of the button.

```
protected void AddContractToQuote(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

Comment: When working in web form, you have to create or recreate all the controllers in your page load function if you want to access them... And it's hell

Comment: @AntoinePelletier How would I do that?

Comment: Wait, you are not creating content dynamically, what's the name of your gridview ?

Comment: The name of my gridview is gvContrato

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used some code that looks like this YEARS ago...

```
for (int x = 0; x < GridViewName.Rows.Count; x++)
{
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow) GridViewName.Rows[x];

    Control contr = (control) row.Cells[1].FindControl("NameOfYourControl");

    contr = //Another similar control that looks like the first, but different

}
```

Comment: It is almost what I want but I am unser with option to use for contr. I want something like this contr.RELOAD(); How can I do this thank you very much.

Comment: You can't just reload it, unless you use client side AJAX or JQUERY. What you have to do in server side code is assign a new value to this control.

Comment: If I wanted to use a client side jquery since it should be faster  how could I do it.